# Sharp edges with a smooth model, how do I fix this?

Tags: shaders

So I'm trying to smooth out the sharp edges of this model, and with the smooth shading there's still some sharp edges, here's what it looks like.

[image]

I've also tried to use Auto Smooth, but it gives off a weird shading that I don't like, and so I just have that off, here's what that looks like..

[image]

Is there any way I can get rid of the sharp edges without using auto smooth?

Comment: Can you upload your project to https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Probably needs more geometry to be properly rounded - you could use a Subdivision Surface Modifier but that will bring the need for supporting geometry to make the mesh look proper.